# Classloader().getReccourse dont returns the source location in exported jar file

Tags: java

`getClass().getResource` works fine in Eclipse and returns the path for a file I want to have access to, but after exporting the JAR file my files don't load anymore.

I already tried to print out my path; in Eclipse the console shows:
`/C:/Users/.../eclipse-workspace/GameJumpAndRun/bin/file/save1`

...but if i run the JAR file by using `cmd` the message is
`file/save1`, and no files have been loaded.

```
System.out.println(getClass().getResource("/file/save"+i).getFile());
file = new File(getClass().getResource("/file/save"+i).getFile());
```

I need the file as a `File` and not as a `BufferedReader`; is there a way to get the same file in both Eclipse and the exported JAR?

Comment: getResource returns a URL, which might not be a file. If your resource is inside a jar, it is not a File. What do you need from it as a File?

Comment: In order to read a resource from a jar file, you should use an InputStream (use `class.getResourceAsStream`) . And note, you can't **write** to a file in your jar. But you could read/write to files from a default folder instead, `File f = Paths.get("file", "save"+i).toFile(); ...`

Comment: Never use `File` to access resources. Use the `URL` returned by `getResource` or the `InputStream` returned by `getResourceAsStream`.

Comment: Files will not work. Use input stream